# Prevent checkbox prop `checked` from updating

Tags: javascript, html

How does one prevent an `<input type="checkbox">` element's .checked property from changing?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rblakeley/8sdtj12o/1/)
I expected this code to alert `false` when the checkbox is clicked, but it alerts `true`.

```
var $elem = $('input');

function handleToggle(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    alert(event.target.checked);
}

$elem.bind('change click', handleToggle);
```

Comment: Please always include the code in question itself...

Comment: Didn't you notice that the checkbox doesn't get checked? If you know that that you are going to prevent the default action, then you know that `!checked` is the value the property will have when the event was processed.

Comment: It's not changing for me.

Comment: The checkbox UI isn't the problem, it's the javascript .checked prop that is changing to `true`, which doesn't match the UI.

Comment: And a side note, as of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Comment: At the moment the event handler is called, `checked` is true because you just intended to select the checkbox. The default action is only performed *after* all handlers have been executed. Only at that point the DOM will be updated to *not* check the checkbox.

Comment: @FelixKling it doesn't make sense to me to not be able to prevent the DOM from updating itself to a `checked` state. This goes against the expected behavior of `preventDefault`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have the wrong expectation of what `preventDefault` does. It simply [sets a flag](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-preventdefault) so that the event handling engine knows what to do **after** the event handler<sup>1</sup> was processed.

> The preventDefault() method must set the canceled flag if the cancelable attribute value is true.

How the event is processed is [explained here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#activation:run-canceled-activation-steps):

> - Run pre-click activation steps on the element.
> - Fire a click event at the element. [...]
> - If this click event is not canceled, run post-click activation steps on the element.
> - If the event is canceled, the user agent must run canceled activation steps on the element instead.

[This is the specification of what happens when a checkbox is clicked](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#checkbox-state-(type=checkbox)):

> If the element is mutable, then: The [pre-click activation steps](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#pre-click-activation-steps) consist of setting the element's [checkedness](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#concept-fe-checked) to its opposite value (i.e. true if it is false, false if it is true), and of setting the element's indeterminate IDL attribute to false. The [canceled activation steps](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#canceled-activation-steps) consist of setting the checkedness and the element's indeterminate IDL attribute back to the values they had before the pre-click activation steps were run.

So you see, the element's `checked` property is set to the opposite value before the event handler is executed and only set to the original value if the event was canceled. But that procedure is run *after* the event handler.

---

<sup>1</sup>: It seems to be not after the current event handler itself but all event handlers that are supposed to be executed.

Comment: Does it not seem counter-intuitive to fire a "checked" event, which updates the DOM, and not provide a way to prevent it? In the execution flow, I would definitely expect something after `preventDefault` to reflect the canceled activation. In every other case where I use `preventDefault`, the lines following reflect that canceled behavior.

Comment: @rblakeley: What's an example for another case? I'm just the messenger. If you don't like this behavior you have to take it to those who write the specification.

Comment: @FelixKing: Thank you for the attention and research. I'm not at all frustrated with you. But do you advocate this behavior? I've always understood `preventDefault` to take effect within the execution flow immediately. But maybe I've been blindly walking through a shooting range without getting hit.

Comment: @FelixKing here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rblakeley/tdng3k3j/) which does not alert the key you pressed as a value on the text input.

Comment: @rblakeley: I always expected `preventDefault` to have an effect only at the very end of the event handler chain. Anyway, your example shows the same behavior if you remove `preventDefault`. During the keypress event the value of the element does not contain the new character. Overall I don't have a strong opinion on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

The event is called when the status of the attribute checked have been already changed to true. You have to put a conditional if you want to always mark the checkbox false. Although i don't see the sense of doing that.

```
var $checkbox = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

function handleToggle(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    if(event.target.checked === true) {
        event.target.checked = false;
    }
    alert(event.target.checked);
}

$checkbox.bind('change click', handleToggle);
```

Cheers!

Comment: The point is I want to do some other stuff before allowing the `checked` property to change. And it needs to work both ways: checked -> unchecked, unchecked -> checked. My goal is to prevent the default behavior, do stuff, and then update the `checked` property

Comment: You can see that problem from an inverse perspective, when the change event, swaps the checked value to true , you can assume that the previous state was false and viceversa. In the end, You can implement your logic and leave the state of the checked  attribute the way you want it to.

Comment: @rblakeley: If you know that the event is prevented, then you know that `!checked` is the value that the checkbox *will* have. Don't see what the problem is here?

Comment: @FelixKling the problem is that the code will not make sense. `!checked` will represent the *actual* `checked` value within the scope of the function. If I pass it around to another handler or validation step - it will continue to be backwards, so any `if` statements will be very confusing. Then when all the handlers are finished, the engine is going to inverse that property on its own with no representative expression in the code.

Comment: @rblakeley: if you pass it to another function you would of course pass the negated checked value. If you have another event handler you can test whether the event is prevented or not. It's only confusing to you because you expect something different. But for others who know about that behavior it won't be confusing.

Comment: @rblakeley Sometimes the verbose of the syntax doesnt explain the expected behaviour. In general, it's a matter of perspective

Answer (score -1):

in the HTML just add 'disabled' to the input element.